# Java: Continue with Label

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int b=10;
        int a= 5;
        jmp0:
          while (b> 10)
          { if (a>5)
              continue jmp0; 
            else 
              continue jmp1; 
          } 

        jmp1: System.out.print("Zulfi");

          }
}
```

I have a question related to above code. Is using “continue jmp0” same as just using “continue;” in the above code and “continue jmp1;” is giving an error because "jmp1" is outside the block?

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`continue` isn't a jump that you can use to go anywhere. It will just move the execution of the code to the **start of the loop** you have labelled.

Labels are only used to mark **loops** you'll want to continue to or break from later. Not random lines of code you want to jump to. So yeah, your `jmp1` label is totally out of scope

Comment: Thanks. This means that "continue jmp0;" would go to next iteration of while loop.

Comment: @user2994783 That's right. I see you're new to SO. **If** you feel the answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use continue with label then your label must be a loop label.